# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY exception while creating Chatter Group through APEX

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-groups

I am trying to create Chatter Groups through APEX using the code below.

```
CollaborationGroup newGroup = new CollaborationGroup();  
newGroup.OwnerId = userId;  
newGroup.NetworkId = communityId;  
newGroup.Name = 'test name';  
newGroup.Description = 'test description';  
newGroup.CollaborationType = 'Public';  
newGroup.IsAutoArchiveDisabled = true;  

insert newGroup;
```

When I run the above code in developer console , its working fine without any exception and creating  Group.

But when I used the same in my code its giving me a "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY" exception.

> Log:--- 18:05:20.635
>   (635748748)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[1139]|System.DmlException: Insert
>   failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: [] 18:05:20.636
>   (636373991)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false 18:05:20.636
>   (636470947)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

Please suggest how to solve above problem .

Thanks
Arabinda

Comment: By the looks of it, either userId or communityId are causing the issue - I would start by checking they are valid group owners/community Ids first

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue?